# Download json at launch of sencha touch 2 app

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm new to Sencha touch and I want to know if I send a request to a server on launch of a Sencha touch 2 application, recieve the application/json file and store it localy, and then use it without requesting each time the server ?
If you have a tutorial it would be great.
Thnx

Answer (score 1):

[Click here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) for first view of how to config your Store.

If you want your Store to load data automatically at startup time, don't forget to set `autoLoad: true` config.

Comment: Thnx for your answer. But how to store it into a file on my device ?